# How to create new rows in pandas by dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with pandas DataFrame - I don't understand how I can create new rows and merge them with a dictionary.

For instanse, I have this dataframe:

```
shops = [{'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'Rexona', 'Value': 10},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'AXE', 'Value': 20},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'Old Spice', 'Value': 30},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'Camel', 'Value': 40},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'Dove', 'Value': 50},   
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rum', 'Location': 'USA', 'Brand': 'Rexona', 'Value': 10},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rum', 'Location': 'USA', 'Brand': 'CIF', 'Value': 20},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rum', 'Location': 'USA', 'Brand': 'Old Spice', 'Value': 30},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rum', 'Location': 'USA', 'Brand': 'Camel', 'Value': 40}]
```

[image: Initial DataFrame]

At the same time, I have a dictionary dataframe with Chain-Brand connection:

```
chain_brands = [{'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Brand': 'Rexona'},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Brand': 'Axe'},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Brand': 'Old Spice'},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Brand': 'Camel'},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Brand': 'Dove'},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Brand': 'CIF'}]
```

[image: Distionary]

So, I need to create new rows and fill them with 0, if brand in Null. It should look like this:

```
output = [{'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'Rexona', 'Value': 10},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'AXE', 'Value': 20},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'Old Spice', 'Value': 30},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'Camel', 'Value': 40},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'Dove', 'Value': 50},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rimme', 'Location': 'UK', 'Brand': 'CIF', 'Value': 0},
     
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rum', 'Location': 'USA', 'Brand': 'Rexona', 'Value': 10},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rum', 'Location': 'USA', 'Brand': 'CIF', 'Value': 20},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rum', 'Location': 'USA', 'Brand': 'Old Spice', 'Value': 30},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rum', 'Location': 'USA', 'Brand': 'Axe', 'Value': 0},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rum', 'Location': 'USA', 'Brand': 'Camel', 'Value': 40},
    {'Chain': 'SeQu', 'Shop': 'Rum', 'Location': 'USA', 'Brand': 'Dove', 'Value': 0}]
```

[image: Result]

Thanks!

Comment: Why did `Value` of the row "USA Camel" changed from 40 to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a multi-index from the `chain_brands` dataframe and then use `groupby` together with `reindex` to solve this:

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(chain_brands.values.T, names=['Chain', 'Brand'])

s = shops.set_index(['Chain', 'Brand']).\
    groupby(['Location', 'Shop']).\
    apply(lambda x: x.reindex(mi, fill_value=0)).\
    drop(columns=['Location', 'Shop']).\
    reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   Location   Shop Chain      Brand  Value
0        UK  Rimme  SeQu     Rexona     10
1        UK  Rimme  SeQu        Axe      0
2        UK  Rimme  SeQu  Old Spice     30
3        UK  Rimme  SeQu      Camel     40
4        UK  Rimme  SeQu       Dove     50
5        UK  Rimme  SeQu        CIF      0
6       USA    Rum  SeQu     Rexona     10
7       USA    Rum  SeQu        Axe      0
8       USA    Rum  SeQu  Old Spice     30
9       USA    Rum  SeQu      Camel     40
10      USA    Rum  SeQu       Dove      0
11      USA    Rum  SeQu        CIF     20
```